# What does “flooded” mean when referring to people?

Tags: meaning

I know the meaning of “flooded” as in “covered with water”,  but what is the meaning here?

> Over 200 students from all over the state flooded the helpline calls on the first day of its launch.

How was “flooded” used here?

Comment: It's not referring to people, it's referring to calls.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is more likely to be:

> Over 200 students from all over the state flooded the helpline **with** calls on the day of its launch.

There were suddenly a large number of incoming calls -- it was as if there was a flood of calls. The word '*flood*' is used here in a figurative sense: a sudden, large in-rush resembling a flood.

We say something is 'flooded with' -- so *with* is required. Also, the first day is 'the day of launch', so the word *first* is incorrect -- there can be only one day of launch.

Comment: Good point about "the first day of its launch" being redundant. The OP could reword the sentence so that *with* wasn't needed by making the calls do the flooding: "Calls from more than 200 students from all over the state flooded the helpline on the day of its launch."

Comment: I'm surprised no one has yet mentioned *metaphor* in any of these answers.

Comment: @JLG The OP was obviously quoting from a source. He might have partly misquoted, though -- dropping the 'with'.

Comment: @Jim I deliberately avoided 'metaphor', saying 'figurative' instead. '*Flood*' has become so widely used this way, we are constantly flooded with all kinds of things but water. On the other hand, an avalanche, a deluge or the like would certainly be a metaphor. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Jim SF in his answer thinks  "... flood doesn't have to consist of water." :-)

Comment: @Kris, yeah I get that "flood" doesn't have to consist of water, but I have to assume that's where it originated, and in my mind that make it a metaphor.  Or maybe there's something I don't understand about metaphors. Are you saying that because 'flood'-as-a-metaphor is in such common use that it has taken on a different meaning and is no longer metaphorical?

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flood?q=flood -- *v.* 3 *arrive in overwhelming amounts or quantities*  [literal?]. And goes on to list later: *figurative: "our switchboard was flooded with calls"*. [ A close match!]

Comment: @Jim Etymologically, *flood* has its origins in words related to *flow* rather than to water.

Comment: @Kris, ok I can easily see "flow". Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The line got covered with students.

over 200 students from all over the state *overwhelmed* the helpline with calls on the first day of its launch.

It means use far beyond normal capacity. Too many askers, too few people to answer the calls on the helpline.
This is often used in context of "the crowd flooded in", or "we flooded the senator's office with letters" - the flood doesn't have to consist of water.

Comment: Do you mean, "Too many askers, too **few** people to answer the calls..."?

Comment: @JLG He means too many callers, too many to answer (to). Even I had to do a double take before noting that too many in both places is correct. Just the wording is awkward.

Comment: @JLG: Thanks. Kris: Not really, I just made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> Over 200 students from all over the state flooded the helpline calls on the first day of its launch.

Here, "flooded" refers to the fact that the telephone lines were *swarmed* by too many people, i.e., over 200 (in your particular case).
Flooded is used to emphasize *"too many in number"*. So it can also be interpreted as:

> Too many (200 in your case) students from all over the state flooded the helpline calls on the first day of its launch.

It is *"too many"* because such a large number (200 here) was not expected.

Another example:

> The mall was *flooded* by people during new year sale.

This is similar to:

> The mall was *crowded* by people during new year sale.

Also same as:

> The mall was *swarmed* by people during new year sale.

Answer (score 0):

As SF stated it means a large amount of people, but it is used to mean the movement of the people. A flood refers to movement, so a sudden surge of people into a room would be considered a "flood" of people.